# Jasmine + Node.js for server side unittesting. How to run tests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine

I need to be able to run unit test for my Node.js application, I decide to use Jasmine framework, because I know t and think it's pretty well solution. But before I use karma as my test runner, but karma do not works for server side development. So, please, advice me a good way to develop unit test for Node.js with Jasmine

Answer (score 2):

im currently using this project to run mt jasmine's test
https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node

you simply need to exec this : 
jasmine-node path/to/your/specs

May be this is not the best tools for running jasmine specs but i use it because it supports coffescript written specs (jasmine-node --coffee specs/

and finally you could use it to make starting "script" like run test before any action

jasmine-node specs/specs1.js && jasmine-node specs/specs2.js && node server.js for example

an other cool tool i use is rewire https://github.com/jhnns/rewire that allow you to mock some methods fir unit testing

i hope it might help you

Comment: Unfortunately, for now jasmine-node is outdated, it supports Jasmine 2.0, but not 2.1+.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Jasmine documentation](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/node.html) you can use 'jasmine' node package. Running `jasmine init` will create basic jasmin.json configuration file, where you can list all your specs.